# Как в триггере для автоматического обновления данных указать условие на изменение столбца?

Tags: sql, oracle, update, триггер

У меня есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    emp_no NUMBER,
    emp_name VARCHAR2(50),
    salary NUMBER,
    manager VARCHAR2(50),
    dept_no NUMBER)
/
CREATE TABLE dept ( 
     Dept_no NUMBER, 
     Dept_name VARCHAR2(50),
     LOCATION VARCHAR2(50))
/
```

Я хотел бы иметь триггер со следующим условием:
когда данные для столбца `dept.dept_no`изменяются вручную (новая запись, изменение предыдущей записи, удаление данных), столбец `emp.dept_no` должен обновляться автоматически.

Понимаю, что начало триггера должно быть:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_no_update 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON dept FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
BEGIN UPDATE emp ...
```

Как правильно задекларировать вторую часть и верно указать, что изменения должны происходить после внесения коррекций именно для колонки `dept_no`?

Comment: А что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Я понимаю, что начало триггера должно быть: 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_no_update
   AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON dept
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE emp ' Вопрос заключается в том как правильно задекларировать вторую часть и верно указать, что изменения должны происходить после внесения коррекций именно для колонки dept_no. Спасибо.

Comment: Внешний ключ с каскадным обновлением и удалением. А триггер нафиг не нужен.

Comment: @Akina Это учебная схема и учебное задание. Сказали, надо триггеры учить, вот и учат. Как сделать правильно, такой задачи на этом этапе обучения нету.

Comment: Ну тогда первый вопрос. *когда данные для столбца `dept_no` в таблице `dept` изменяются вручную (новая запись, изменение предыдущей записи, удаление данных), столбец `dept_no` в таблице `emp` должен обновляться автоматически.* В какой именно записи (или записях) таблицы `emp` менять? особенно - для случая вставки новой записи...

Comment: @u_lialia Напишите триггер, как вы это поняли, пусть даже не рабочий.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что данные для столбца dept_no управляются 2мя таблицами: emp и dept. Таблица emp основная. И если пользователь поменял значение в таблице dept и забыл внести коррективы в таблицу emp - данные в двух таблицах будут отличаться. Поэтому мне необходимо автоматическое обновление столбца dept_no для таблицы emp. И обязательно нужно применить триггер

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как применить условие, что именно после внесения/ изменения данных для столбца dept_no в таблице dept, столбец dept_no таблицы emp должен 'взять' то же значение: 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_no_update AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON dept FOR EACH ROW DECLARE BEGIN UPDATE

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Условие, что измененился именно заданный столбец в таблице, следует указать оператором `WHEN` до PL/SQL блока, то есть в «первой части» триггера:

```
create or replace trigger dept_no_update 
after delete or update on dept for each row 
when (coalesce (new.dept_no, -old.dept_no ) != old.dept_no)
declare
begin 
    update emp set dept_no = :new.dept_no
    where dept_no = :old.dept_no; 
end;
/

Trigger DEPT_NO_UPDATE compiled
```

---

PS условие на срабатывание по `INSERT` опустил, так как в вопросе нет информации, что должно произойти в случая вставки новой записи.